# Excepcion en consulta sql --> HOUR_OF_DAY: 0 -> 1

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Amigos buenas tardes,

Genero una consulta que puede traer hasta 250 mil registros, cuando genero la consulta me arroja este mensaje de error `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 0 -> 1`, pero si limito la consutla a unos 100 mill se genera sin ningun problema, estube revisando y la consulta tiene un campo de tipo fecha que si lo retiro no se presenta el problema.

Este campo fecha_nacimiento  es de tipo timestamp.

SQL

`String query = "SELECT DISTINCT p.nombres, p.apellidos, p.genero, p.num_documento, p.fecha_nacimiento, p.correo, p.telefono, p.celular, p.contacto_adicional, c.label, a.nombre FROM pacientes p JOIN ciudades c ON (p.ciudad_pertence_centroranal = c.idciudades) JOIN aseguradoras a ON (p.idaseguradora = a.idaseguradoras)";`

obtengo los datos y luego mediante un **for** recorro el array para obtener los datos, cuando voy a obtener el resultList en la siguiente linea es que arroja la excepcion.

```
  List<Object[]> result =  entityManager.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();
  List<ReportePacientes> pacientes = new ArrayList<ReportePacientes>();
```

Dejo la respuesta completa de la excepcion, Agradezco me puedan colaborar

````
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1360)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1288)
    org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:261)
    com.proximate.service.jpa.ExportarBasesJpa.getPacientes(ExportarBasesJpa.java:71)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.getPacientes(Unknown Source)
    com.proximate.actionsAsService.Reportes.ExportarBases.ExportarPacientes(ExportarBases.java:116)
    com.proximate.actionsAsService.Reportes.ExportarBases.execute(ExportarBases.java:76)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor.intercept(JSONInterceptor.java:172)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.proximate.interceptors.SessionInterceptor.intercept(SessionInterceptor.java:33)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)```
````

Comment: y la clase reportepacientes?

Comment: Hola, ¿Has validado que todos tus parámetros coincidan con tu zona horaria?